# How to check whether avatar changed?

Tags: java, image, selenium, assert

I need to test(Java) through Assert if avatar on web page has been changed on another. 
How would I do it?

So far I only came to the idea of taking screenshots before and after.

Comment: Locate the element, check the `href` attribute of the image tag. Or is the href not changing? If so, you will have to extract the `href`, download the image and compare the picture with the old picture (for example pixel by pixel, rather simple). Your question is unfortunately very broad, contains no detail about how the website in question looks and is structured or details on how you save the original picture and so on. Hence, downvoted and voting to close because unclear/needs details.

Answer (score -1):

Mabye try to see if the id or href was changed

Comment: This is not a full answer, rather a comment. Please see [answer]. I am aware that it is not possible to really write much more or go into detail based on what OP provided. But then rather post a comment and wait for an edit.